# Time Series forecasting with Bidirectional LSTMs

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, bidirectional, bilstm

I have implemented a Bidirectional LSTM which predicts a certain profile by using a windowing input in tensorflow. Conceptually it makes sense to me during the training phase.

Once the model is trained I use it to predict future and evaluate against a test set. However, I am unsure what happens to the backward LSTM cells that were originally trained with information passed from future to past. Does the network first do a forward pass in time and then a backward pass to give an output? Could someone please elaborate how does the network work in testing phase.

Network architecture

[image: 1]

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to find some resources online but couldn't find a convincing answer

Comment: No unfortunately not

Comment: I have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446615/can-bilstm-be-applied-to-timeseries#comment134800434_76446615 and I still have the same doubt.